# Flash AS3 (shape class) CPU usage and optimization

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, line, shapes

I'm new to Flash Actionscript 3.0 and object programming in general. I'm trying to create a simple game, which is drawing a shape based on steering.

```
public class Player extends Shape
{
    public var X,Y,v,vX,vY,size,a,r:Number;
    public var k,counter,leftKey,rightKey,_color:uint;  
    public var line:Shape = new Shape();
    public var dot:Shape = new Shape(); 

  /*...*/
  /*constructor, giving values to variables here, not important*/       
  /*...*/

   public function Move():void
    {

        a=a+0.05*k; 
       //player controls k parameter k=0 by default 
       //k=1 when right key pressed
       //k=-1 when left key pressed

        vX=v*Math.cos(a);
        vY=v*Math.sin(a);

        X=X+vX;
        Y=Y+vY;

        dot.x=X+vX*size/(2*v);
        dot.y=Y+vY*size/(2*v);

        if (counter==0)
        {
            line.graphics.lineTo(X,Y);
            if (Math.random()<0.008) counter=12;
        } else 
        {
            line.graphics.moveTo(X, Y);
            counter--;
        }
    }
```

}

Function Move is in my Player class, which is called from inifinite TimerEvent function in my Main Class

```
public function mainLoop(TimerEvent:Event):void
{           
    for (var i:uint=0; i<players; i++) player[i].Move();
}
```

It seems to be working well at the beginning but after some time CPU usage raises dramatically and game becomes unplayble. I belivie it's caused by my shape (line) getting more and more complex.

Is there some reasonable way to optimize it? Can I somehow draw a line in less consuming way? I tried to convert it to bitmap but that looked ugly and didn't really help.

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Is counter maintains the current count of players?

Comment: @abhinav No, variable counter is just responsible for creating random gaps in line - doesn't matter in my problem. I set number of player manually, but CPU usage is increasing in time even if there is only one player.

Comment: I'm guessing part of the problem is constantly drawing(not to mention not clearing). I suggest drawing the line once, then simply moving or rotating the object (using the .x,.y,.rotation properties or .transform.matrix if you want  lower level control). If you want to draw the trails consider using a BitmapData object bellow your shape into which you [draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()), passing the shape's transformation matrix as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in assuming that your slowdown in coming from your shape code - vector data is redrawn every frame in flash, so the more complex it is, the longer it takes to draw. Some solutions, depending on what you're willing to do:

- Your fidelity is way to high - you're calling your `Move` function every frame; you probably don't need it that high, as the difference in movement since the last frame is probably less than a pixel. Sample your position every X frames instead (where X is the level of fidelity your willing to go down to). This can be done with a simple counter in the enter frame
- If you don't need to keep the entire history of the drawing, put all your points into an array/vector, culling the length as needed. Then every frame, do a `line.graphics.clear()` and just draw the points in the array
- If you *do* need to keep the entire history, then keep a `BitmapData` under your line (e.g. the size of the stage). Every so often, draw the `line` to the `BitmapData` and call `clear()` on your graphics to get right of the vector data. You shouldn't notice any loss in quality (set `smoothing` to `true` when you're drawing)

I'd do the first point in any case, then choose between the second and third, depending on your use case

Comment: I've tested it, and believe me, I'm calling move function only as often as needed to make movement look smooth. Anyway your third point seems to be working well, however the drawn line looks much worse in its bitmap version comparing to vector one- bitmap it's terribly pixelized. I'm not sure why and if its possible to somehow improve its appearance. Thank you!

Comment: is `smoothing` set to true when you draw the bitmap? It should be `myBMD.draw( line *(or stage)*, null, null, null, null, **true**);` If that's not doing it, then try the `drawWithQuality()` method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#drawWithQuality() - normally, when you `draw()` to a `BitmapData`, there should be no loss in quality - I use it all the time to cache vector graphics

Comment: also note that if your `Bitmap` is scaled, or rotated, you'll suffer from artifacts (similar to if you zoomed and rotated an image in Photoshop), so `draw()` with that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment, try something like this:

```
public class Player extends Shape
{
    public var X,Y,v,vX,vY,size,a,r:Number;
    public var k,counter,leftKey,rightKey,_color:uint;  
    public var line:Shape = new Shape();
    public var dot:Shape = new Shape(); 

  /*...*/
  /*constructor, giving values to variables here, not important*/       
  /*...*/
    public function Player(){
        //draw shapes
        graphics.lineStyle(1);
        graphics.drawCircle(0,0,r);
        graphics.lineTo(size,0);//can't test this now, but make sure the line is in the same direction as rotation 0 (guessing it's to the right)
        //your other constructor code here
    }
   public function Move():void
    {

        a=a+0.05*k; 
       //player controls k parameter k=0 by default 
       //k=1 when right key pressed
       //k=-1 when left key pressed

        vX=v*Math.cos(a);
        vY=v*Math.sin(a);

        X=X+vX;
        Y=Y+vY;

        x=X+vX*size/(2*v);
        y=Y+vY*size/(2*v);
        rotation = a * 57.2957795;//quick'n'dirty radians to degrees
    }
```

and if you want to draw the trails you can try something like this:

```
var canvas:Bitmap = new BitmapData(state.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0xFF000000);
var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,.1);   
public function mainLoop(TimerEvent:Event):void
{           
    for (var i:uint=0; i<players; i++) {
        player[i].Move();
        canvas.draw(player[i],player[i].transform.concatenatedMatrix,ct);
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

**Update**
Here is a standalone code snippet to illustrate the idea above(which has untested syntax):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class PlayerMoveTest extends Sprite {
        private var keys:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        private var players:Vector.<Player> = new Vector.<Player>();
        private var trails:BitmapData;
        private var fade:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,.1);
        public function PlayerMoveTest() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event):void{
            trails = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0x00FFFFFF);
            addChild(new Bitmap(trails));
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < 2; i++){
                var p:Player = addChild(new Player(10+i*10)) as Player;
                p.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
                p.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
                players.push(p);
            }
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        }
        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
        private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            keys[e.keyCode] = null;
        }
        private function update(e:Event):void{
            if(keys[Keyboard.LEFT] != undefined)  {players[0].a -= .05;players[1].a += .05;}
            if(keys[Keyboard.RIGHT] != undefined) {players[0].a += .05;players[1].a -= .05;}
            if(keys[Keyboard.UP] != undefined)    {players[0].s += .15;players[1].s -= .15;}
            if(keys[Keyboard.DOWN] != undefined)  {players[0].s -= .15;players[0].s += .15;}
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < players.length; i++) {
                players[i].move();
                trails.draw(players[i],players[i].transform.concatenatedMatrix,fade);
            }
        }
    }

}
import flash.display.*;
class Player extends Shape{
    public var vx:Number,vy:Number,a:Number,size:Number,r:Number,s:Number;
    public function Player(size:Number){
        init(size);
    }
    private function init(size:Number):void{
       vx = vy = a = s = 0;
       this.size = size;
       this.r = size * .25;
       graphics.lineStyle(1);
       graphics.drawCircle(0,0,r);
       graphics.lineTo(size,0);     
    }
    public function move():void{
        rotation = a * 57.2957795;
        vx = Math.cos(a) * s;
        vy = Math.sin(a) * s;
        x += vx;
        y += vy;
        if(x < 0) x = 0;
        if(y < 0) y = 0;
        if(x > stage.stageWidth) x = stage.stageWidth-width;
        if(y > stage.stageHeight) y = stage.stageHeight-height;
    }
}
```

You can test this code [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/ltRx) and here's a preview:

[image: preview]

Use the arrow keys to drive(up arrow accelerates, left/right steer).
The first player is the smaller one, having the correct controls, the other is simply mirroring the previous controls)

Comment: In general idea is good, but the code is not working at all, moreover some parts don't make sesne to me so I moified it. Thanks for giving me an idea!

Comment: @Rames See my updates above, the code initially posted wasn't tested, I thought that was enough to illustrate the idea. I've posted another snippet you can run. Feel free to vote/mark as you see fit ;)